# iPad Mini Not Restoring?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, password, restore

The pass-code has been entered incorrectly on my iPad so many times that a screen showed up saying:

> iPad is Disabled. Connect to iTunes

I have tried two methods to restoring the iPad.

1. Connect the iPad to the computer. Hold down the home and power buttons at the same time. When the screen goes blank, wait two seconds, then release both buttons.  I went to Itunes and held down the correct buttons until apple recognized iTunes recognized the iPad was in recovery mode. I then chose the `restore` option on the screen. When Itunes finished and restarted, the same screen showed up: `iPad  is Disabled. Connect to iTunes`
2. Hold down the volume/home/power button at the same time till the apple icon shows up, release all the buttons. When this happened, the Apple diagnostics screen showed up and when I clicked `Exit Diagnostics`, the Ipad restarted, and went to the same  `iPad  is Disabled. Connect to Itunes` screen. When I chose the second option `Start Diagnostics`, It told me to go to `apple.com/support`.

Is there any way to fix this and restore the iPad? I do not need to save my old data.

Comment: Connect your iOS device to your computer and open iTunes. ...
    While your device is connected, force restart it: ...
    When you see the option to Restore or Update, choose Restore. ...
    Wait for the process to finish.

Comment: I mentioned in my question as `Method 1` that I followed the instructions on Itunes and the Ipad returned to the same `disabled` screen. I'm sorry if i was not clear enough and have edited the question.

Comment: so it is `disabled` because you entered the wrong password repentantly, do you now the right password ?

Comment: I think I still know it. The iPad has been disabled for over a year!

Answer (score 1):

Restoring it from iTunes should have worked. But this only works if you have previously synced your device with iTunes and have a backup stored on your computer.

If you know the right password... do following.

Try to back up the iOS device in iTunes

The first thing you should try to unlock your disabled device is a simple iTunes backup.

Connect your iOS device to your computer via USB and open iTunes. Select the device in the upper right-hand corner to display its properties in the main screen.

[image]

iTunes backup

Click on the "Back Up Now" button to start a sync.

You may be prompted to type in your password on your iOS device to start the sync because the device is locked.

Once you have typed in your password, you can cancel the back up and start using your device.

Comment: When I connect the iPad to iTunes and open iTunes, I get a prompt to allow access to the iPad. When I click `ok` this shows up: `iTunes could not connect to this iPad. an unknown error occured (0xE8000015) `

Comment: @Redline so it is still blocked ! This trick only works if you have previously synced your device with iTunes

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using iTunes, you can also use iCloud to unlock:
1. Visit the iCloud webpage with another device and log in to your Apple account.
2. Select "Find iPhone" among various functions on the page.
3. At the top of the page you jump to, click All Devices.
4. Select the iPad that is now disabled among all displayed devices.
5. Find the "Erase" button, all data and screen lock on iPad will be erased.
6. iPad will restart automatically and you can access iPad without screen lock.
If you have synced data with iTunes before, this method is also worth trying: https://www.fonecope.com/fix-ipad-is-disabled-connect-to-itunes.html#Part2